# Why are normal numbers important?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

I'm studying normal numbers for my university dissertation - in particular whether or not algebraic numbers are normal.

One thing I cannot find anywhere is why it matters. I'm not expecting a real world application, I just want to know, will it be of any significance, in any area of mathematics, if we can prove that all irrational algebraic numbers are normal. Or, for that matter, if we could prove that any number, say pi or e, was normal. Does it have any application?

Any ideas, however vague, would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's just interesting because, although almost all real numbers are normal, there is literally no constructed number that has been proven to be normal in all bases. (afaik? I'm all ears if anyone happens to know of one.)

Comment: If you can prove that all irrational algebraic numbers are normal, you will be famous.  At least among mathematicians.  Would that matter?

Comment: @Dustan: Depending upon what you mean by "constructed", your comment may not be true.  See e.g. http://webdiis.unizar.es/~elvira/publicaciones/normal7.pdf.  (Is there some reasonable meaning of "constructed" that you have in mind for which what you say is true?)

Comment: well, ideally, I'd say computable to arbitrary precision by an explicitly constructed procedure, but of course I understand that's a much stronger condition.

Comment: @Dustan: Did you follow the link in my last comment?  It does what you've asked for and more (by giving an upper bound on the computation time).

Comment: I had opened the link, but I'm still on the learning curve when it comes to reading and understanding papers. Thanks!

Comment: @Dustan: No problem.  (This is not an area of great expertise on my part either.)  The following paper seems a bit more clear on doing what you ask: http://math.berkeley.edu/~slaman/papers/poly.pdf.  Let me also say that a web search turns up other papers which claim that "no specific examples of absolutely normal numbers are known", so my earlier assertion that one must be precise about what one is asking for here seems to be critical.

Comment: @GEdgar, even if Briony can only prove that there exists an irrational algebraic that is normal, then Briony will be famous.